# Add all list items to string python

Tags: python-3.6

I have a list
`"SecretList"`: `["GitHubToken","GitHubUser"]`

```
def handler(event, context):                 
    response_data = {}
    try:
        param = " "
        param_value = [event['SecretList']]
        for i in range(len(param_value)):
            param[i] = “ “.join(map(str, param_value[1])
            value = get_parameters(param[i])
            print (value)

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

Need the list items in seperate strings

```
str1=GitHubToken
str2=GitHubUser
```

My logic is not working , can someone suggest me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following logic:

```
def handler(event, context):                 
response_data = {}
try:
    param = {}
    param_value = event['SecretList']
    for idx, item in enumerate(param_value):
        print (idx)
        value = get_parameters(param_value[idx])
        print (value)

except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Comment: Please correct my mistakes on the function, though i made it work

Comment: @NeErAj Kumar, Please suggest a better solution. The above logic does not work when the value is only 1

Comment: I didn't understand which vars has 1. Add get_parameters method code also

Comment: param_value[idx] == item both are equal according to your code.So don't use param_value[idx] in method

Answer (score 0):

```
def handler(event, context):                 
    response_data = {}
    try:
        param = {}
        param_value = event['SecretList']
        for index, value in enumerate(param_value):
             param.update({'str{}'.format(index): value})
        print param  #output:  {'str1': 'GitHubUser', 'str0': 'GitHubToken'}

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

Comment: Sorry, This outputs the value on a list. I would need the items of a list on seperate string which i pass to another function def get_parameters(param_value):    I get the param_value (on the main function) as a list and then iterate each of the items in the list to  a string and each of the string passed to another function